# No closure for delegates in anonymous function inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, delegates, closures, anonymous-function

**UPDATE:** turns out that this is a problem with the Mono compiler used by Unity3D. I'm not sure if the current version of Mono (3.10.0) fixes it, but the old version used in the engine (2.0.5) seems to not implement this feature for delegates, or simply work as it should.

---

At some point in a game I'm developing (in the Unity3D engine), the player unlocks several items at once. For each of them I must present a simple information dialog that the user must click to advance to the next, until all have been read.

I have a simple C# static method to show a dialog (just a colored overlay with some text in Unity, and NOT in any way related to C# UI frameworks):

```
ConfirmationDialog.Create("Item X Unlocked!", callback);
```

When the user finally presses the dialog, `callback` is called.

I wanted to **chain all dialogs** so that each one is only created when the previous is clicked on, so I tried this:

```
Action callback = delegate {};

foreach (string item in unlockedItems) {
    var cb = callback;  // I though this would create a closure for delegates too
    callback = (() => ConfirmationDialog.Create(item + " Unlocked!", cb));
}
callback();
```

This made sense in my head, as the anonymous function would use a different "cb" delegate in each iteration of the cycle. It seems I'm mistaken, though, as **this code seems to result in the same dialog being repeatedly called** when clicked, as would happen in a recursive function (which I guess is what it became).

I know I can, for example, do `int value = i;` inside a for loop (where `i` is the loop iterator) to use the correct value of `i` inside the anonymous function (I found a lot of material on this). Delegates seem different, but what in particular makes them not work in the same way? Or am I doing something terribly wrong? Could I do this chaining in some similar way? I say "similar" because I can certainly think of doing this in other - more complicated - ways...

Note: please DO correct me if my use of the words "closure", "delegate", etc, is not right :)

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking, but it seems you're making this needlessly complex.  Since you have a loop anyhow, why not just call ConfirmationDialog.Create() immediately in the loop.  Less code, less complexity.

Comment: Because that would create all dialogs at once, and I need each one to be displayed in sequence. They have a certain transparency, and therefore the player would see the ones behind the frontmost one, which is undesirable. There are also other problems :)

Comment: Is this an issue of creating the dialogs from a non-UI thread?  If created on the UI thread as modal dialogs, you would see one at a time (at least for WinForms and WPF... not sure what framework you are using).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, it was probably not clear but I'm not using any UI framework of C#. I'm using Unity3D for developing the game. It just happens that I'm using C# as the language. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: Whatever the issue, it's particular to Unity and/or your `ConfirmationDialog.Create()` implementation. I.e. it seems that the `callback` parameter doesn't do what you seem to think it does. When I implement a WinForms version of this code, it does exactly what I (and you) would expect: each dialog is displayed in succession. Make sure that the `callback` parameter you're passing actually doesn't get invoked until the user dismisses the dialog. You should post a more complete code example, one that includes the `ConfirmationDialog.Create()` method. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Argh. After reading your comment I created a build of my game for the Windows Store, which uses the .NET compiler instead of the old version of Mono that Unity uses. Like you said, it worked flawlessly as expected. It may simply be something that wasn't implemented in the Mono compiler at the time (I have no idea if it is now). I wish Unity would update the Mono version used in the engine... It seems it's using version 2.0.5 and the current one is 3.10.0... Anyway, thanks @PeterDuniho.

Comment: I would like to ask what is the correct (StackOverflow) way to proceed regarding the question. I've updated it. Should it be closed without an answer? Should I create an answer instead of the update? Thanks!

Comment: If you can investigate further, so that you fully understand the difference between the Unity/Mono-compiler scenario and the VS/.NET scenario and can include those specific details in an answer, then yes...I'd say you should answer your own question with those details. Without those details, this question seems of minimal usefulness to others and in that case, probably should just be deleted. But if you want to post your answer regardless, don't worry...if it's too much a deviation from SO norms, it'll get moderated. You can't really go wrong either way.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control over the `ConfirmationDialog.Create("Item X Unlocked!", callback);` API? If so, instead of taking a callback, you should look at refactoring that to use `Task`. If you had that, you could simply chain a bunch of tasks as continuations and have them execute one after the other.

I know with game development, these things are often quite asynchronous in nature, the way UI gets shown and subsequently reacted to ... so you could use [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/02/9685804.aspx) so you have a handle to something that you can signal that your task is done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! ConfirmationDialog is actually a class of mine. Unfortunately, Unity's Mono compiler seems to be what results in my issue (see comments in question). Furthermore, it doesn't have access to the asynchronous libraries that .NET has, so I cannot use this solution :( I'll find an alternative. Just maybe not as simple as I hoped. Thanks again.